# Kubernetes gives an internal source IP although externalTrafficPolicy is set to Local

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, weave

Our Kubernetes cluster includes an nginx load balancer that forwards the requests to other pods.

However, the nginx sees local source IPs and therefore cannot set the correct X-Real-IP header. I tried setting the externalTrafficPolicy value of nginx to "Local" but the IP does not change.

Section of the nginx service config:

```
 "selector": {
  "app": "nginx-ingress",
  "component": "controller",
  "release": "loping-lambkin"
},
"clusterIP": "10.106.1.182",
"type": "LoadBalancer",
"sessionAffinity": "None",
"externalTrafficPolicy": "Local",
"healthCheckNodePort": 32718
```

Result:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:444
X-Request-ID: dd3310a96bf154d2ac38c8877dec312c
X-Real-IP: 10.39.0.0
X-Forwarded-For: 10.39.0.0
```

We use a bare metal cluster with metallb.

Comment: I found out that weave needs to be configured using `NO_MASQ_LOCAL=1` to respect the `externalTrafficPolicy` property.

Comment: We run into the same issue, the only difference is we are on the flannel network, do you know how to turn off masquerade on flannel ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about flannel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that weave needs to be configured using `NO_MASQ_LOCAL=1` to respect the externalTrafficPolicy property

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the IPVS implementation for services of type LoadBalancer : https://github.com/google/metallb/issues/290